# How to generate mdb files when building release version in MonoDevelop?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

When build release version, there is no mdb file in the same folder. I'd like to have mdb file. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project's Build/Compiler options (for the Release configuration), set "Debug information" to "Full"